# Modeless MsgBox, Error trapping, .Find

Tags: vba, excel

I have a subroutine that searches for an occurrence of a string in another workbook. I'm trying to get an error message to pop up if the string can't be found (it's most likely due to spelling mistakes), as vbModeless, and allows to user to click on the cell in the searched sheet with the correct value. Then I'd like to resume the search with the new value.

I'm at the moment stuck on making my simple MsgBox to be modeless.
Can anyone help? So far I have (simplified):

```
With ...
    On Error GoTo UserSelect
    celladdress = .Range("a1:bb100").Find("searchstring").Address
```

And my error label:

```
UserSelect:
    MsgBox("Select the cell with the correct spelling") vbModeless
    newstring = ActiveCell.Value
    searchstring = newstring
    Resume
```

I think it's the Modeless MsgBox giving me grief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that you can use vbModeless with msgbox. That is for use with the Show method of a user form.

What you probably need to do is create a user form that has a refedit control and a button on it. They can then pick a cell with the refedit control. When the user clicks on the button set a public variable on the form with the cell reference the selected.

Then you you need to use ".Show vbModal" on the user form and read off the cell they selected from the form public variable.

Edit:

Actually, you shouldn't need the public variable as the refedit control should be a public property of the form anyway.

Comment: Ah. How could I make a simple User Form to do essentially the same. Ie: pause the running of the background code until the user selects a cell and clicks a button?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on the requirements here. Given a search string of *dgo* and a worksheet with cells containing *bird*, *cat* and *dog*. Do you want the user to:

(a) edit the cell containing *dog* and change it to say *dgo* instead

This would use the modal form and RefEdit control outlined by andynormancx. Like a MsgBox, the modal form pauses the macro until the form is closed

(b) allow the user to click on the cell containg *dog* and then re-run the search with *dog* as the search term

This is more complicated. I think that you would need to look at events here. This is fine if your subroutine is pretty much standalone but if it is part of a larger program then this could require substantial rewriting

Comment: (a) Sort of - I want a 'reference' cell to be updated to that each time I run the macro, it looks at that cell value. Ie, if it was wrong to begin with, the user's input replaces that 'reference' value, and the error doesn't occur again.